# PHP foreach loop array error as "Undefined variable" but the value exists

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, key

I have a variable $users with inside an array. Dumping it I have:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["'ev_id'"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["'user_email'"]=>
    string(17) "zoom@zoom.com"
    ["'status_role'"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["'registration'"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["'confirmation'"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["'participation'"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["'ev_id'"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["'user_email'"]=>
    string(24) "miao@miao.com"
    ["'status_role'"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["'registration'"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["'confirmation'"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["'participation'"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    ["'ev_id'"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["'user_email'"]=>
    string(20) "bau@bau.com"
    ["'status_role'"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["'registration'"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["'confirmation'"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["'participation'"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

This is my code:

```
echo "<pre>";var_dump($users);
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
echo $value['ev_id'];
}
```

I am becoming crazy as I want simply loop and echo the "ev_id" value in the array but I receive an error as:

```
Notice:  Undefined index: ev_id
```

The value "ev_id" exists, you can see in the dump. Why I receive an Undefined index?

Comment: Why does it look like you have single  quotes around that key name? How are you building that array? [That looks like that is your problem](https://3v4l.org/qtErs)

Comment: John you are perfectly right. I have done this array by posting from a form but I added in the name of each field the quote as for example <select name="user['.$x.']['ev_id']" id="ev_id" class="form-control">. Removing the quote on ev_id it works perfectly now. Thank you!

Comment: Nice to see a Happy ending :)